# How to highlight the selection in Emacs keybinding of Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, emacs

I have searched the Web for this, but with no luck.  Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused by your question since the selection is always highlighted in Eclipse :/

Comment: The eclipse editor behaves like what you said when in its default key scheme.  It changes when the scheme is switched to emacs key scheme.
Thanks.

Comment: I see you just accepted my answer: did you find a proper eclipse command to bind to 'Control-space' in order to achieve the emacs selection mechanism ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described [here](http://lists.apple.com/archives/webobjects-dev/2007/Dec/msg00042.html), you can set emacs key binding to work in component editor in Eclipse

Go to `Preferences -> General -> Keys`.

- Change Scheme to Emacs if you haven't done so already, so you can easily
  spot the emacs key bindings.
- Sort by Category and look at the "`Text Editing`" categories
- Find the commands that you care about, e.g. `Next Column`, `Previous Column`
- Select that command and click "`Copy Command`"
- Set the binding to the key by pressing the keys, e.g. press `Control-f` to
  generate "`^F`".
- Change "`When:`" to "`Editing Components`".
- Repeat for all the key bindings you care about.

So if, in emacs, selection is done by setting the mark (`Control-Space`) at the start of the region, then moving the point to to the end of the region, you could associate the appropriate shortcut to:

```
Text Editing > Select Text Start
Text Editing > Select Text End
```

Comment: After binding "Control-Space" to the command "Select Text Start",  I found that the eclipse editor always highlight the region which ranges from the first line of current file to the mark.  Any suggestion?
Thanks again.

Comment: I will look again at the various select command, but if none fit the expected behavior, it will be tricky: a command and its associated key would have to be defined in order to properly select the text.

Answer (score 5):

Try using the Emacs+ plugin available here:

http://www.mulgasoft.com/emacsplus

It provides a HUGE range of functionality - including the selection highlighting that you're looking for - that really helps the move from Emacs. I've only been using it for a couple of days, but it appears stable and integrates very well with the editor.